# Reverse proxy for mixed tcp, udp, and http services

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, tcp, haproxy, udp

I'm building an architecture that will be hosting various services which individually maybe listening on a variable number of ports that could be mixed protocols.

I want to map these services to unique subdomains and reverse proxy inbound requests to the external ports to corresponding internal ports.

Currently I'm using Nginx with a tcp module installed. This gives me http, and tcp support. However I just found that Nginx doesn't support UDP. It seems like maybe with a custom module I could support UDP but thats a separate issue. I'm also having issues with mapping multiple TCP services to  subdomains using the Nginx module.

I'm hoping there is another proxy solution out there that might be better suited for this. Or a combination of tools.

Edit: The only thing I've found that might fit this role is:
http://freecode.com/projects/proxymini
http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm#proxymini

but I can't tell if its unix friendly or windows only and might not be a reverse proxy

Comment: UDP is the wild card here. Exactly what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm spinning up docker containers on subdomains. These containers can have X amount of services. Listening on Y amount of ports that use Z protocols. With my current setup I can spin up a container that has TCP and HTTP services in it. However a container with a UDP port will not be forwarded to properly

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "TCP services to subdomains"? TCP itself it not aware of whatever DNS name was used to connect to the service. The application level protocol would have to specify something like a host header.

Comment: You need more IP addresses, not a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is not a reverse proxy but DNS